# How to change location from one state to another state using ui-sref in Angular Js?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have states

```
 .state('main', {
              url: '/',
              template: '<div ui-view=""></div>'
             })
 .state('main.header', {
                url: 'header',
                templateUrl: 'modules/core/views/header.html'
           })

 .state('main.header.sidemenu', {
                url: '/sidemenu',
                templateUrl: 'modules/admin/views/adminsidemenu.html'
            })
 .state('main.header.sidemenu.businesslist', {
               url: '^/business/businesslist',
               templateUrl:'modules/business/views/business.list.view.html',
        })
  .state('main.header.sidemenu.tabs', {
               url: '',
               templateUrl:'modules/business/views/tabs.business.view.html',
          })
 .state('main.header.sidemenu.tabs.profile', {
               url: '^/business/profile',
               templateUrl:'modules/business/views/tabs.business.view.html',
          })
```

My html code in state->**main.header.sidemenu.tabs.profile**-> template

```
<li>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)"
     ui-sref="main.header.sidemenu.businesslist">XXXXX</a>
</li>
```

Then it throwing error **Could not resolve 'branchUrl' from state ->main.header.sidemenu.tabs** when I click anchor

How to solve this issue.
Can you please help me to this?

Comment: could you add your `state` configuration?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you have not defined the `branchUrl` state. Please check inside your `state` configuration and make sure `branchUrl` should be there.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error usually means, that some part of (js) code was not loaded. That the state which is inside of ui-sref is missing . You don't need to specify the parent, states work in an document oriented way so, instead of specifying parent: main, you could just change the state to main.header

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/main.html");

$stateProvider.state('app', {
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "url"
});
$stateProvider.state('main', {
    url: '/main',
    templateUrl: "url1"
});
$stateProvider.state('main.header', {
    url: '/main/header',
    templateUrl: "url2"
});

$stateProvider.state('main.header.sidemenu', {
    url: "/main/header/sidemenu",
    templateUrl: "url 3"
});
$stateProvider.state('main.header.sidemenu.businesslist', {
    url: "/main/header/sidemenu/businesslist",
    templateUrl: "url 4"
});
```

for deep nesting you need to define all the states . hope it will help you